# On the simplification using trigonometric functions

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, matrix, math, linear-algebra

Assume I have a matrix $D$ whose its entries are as below :

[image]

Where $A$ and $B$ can be written using using the trigonometric functions for (1) as:

[image]

My question, Is it possible to simplify (1)
 more? how can we do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe:

$$ \cos( \alpha ) e^{j \beta} = \frac{e^{j \alpha}+e^{-j\alpha}}{2} \cdot e^{j \beta} =\frac{1}{2} \left( e^{j (\beta + \alpha)}+e^{j(\beta - \alpha)} \right) $$

Where:

$$ \alpha = (k-1)(2n-1) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2N} = \frac{ 2nk - 2n - k + 1}{4} \cdot \frac{2\pi}{N} $$

$$ \beta = nk \cdot \frac{2\pi}{N} $$

Plug this in and you can transform jbondu's equation into the sum of two pure complex exponentials.  That might be considered a simplification.  This also allows for the definition of your matrix as the sum of two matrices.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), you can simplify like this:
$$
[d]_{k,n} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{N}\left( \cos{\left[ \frac{(k-1)(2n-1)\pi}{2N} \right]} e^{j\frac{2 \pi nk}{N}} \right)
$$

I think we can't simplify more.

PS: If you use your expressions of $A$ and $B$ and again the Euler's formula, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The cosine and sine terms can be combined to a single exponential function using:

$$ \cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta) = e^{j\theta}$$

Comment: I see .. but it won't be simplified, just writing it in exponential term.

Comment: You have two distinct frequencies so to that extent they are in simplest form other than doing this

Answer (score 1):

You can use, from [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), the fact that 
$$
\exp\left(j\theta\right) = \cos\theta + j\sin\theta \qquad \text{with}\qquad j = \sqrt{-1} 
$$
and combine the sine and cosine into exponential terms. You basically have the first exponential inside the square bracket equal to 
$$
\exp\big[j\left(6\pi nk + \pi -k\pi - 2\pi n \right)\big] = \exp\bigg\{j\big[k\pi \left(6n - 1\right) - \pi\left(2n - 1\right)  \big]\bigg\}  
$$
Which can be simplified further as follows:
\begin{align}
\exp\bigg\{j\big[k\pi \left(6n - 1\right) - \pi\left(2n - 1\right)  \big]\bigg\} &= \exp\bigg\{j\big[k\pi \left(6n - 1\right)\big]\bigg\}\cdot\exp\bigg\{-j\big[\pi\left(2n - 1\right)  \big]\bigg\} \\
&= \left(-1\right)^k\cdot \left(-1\right)\ \qquad \forall \ k\in \mathbb Z\ \text{and}\ \forall n\in \mathbb Z\\
& = \left(-1\right)^{k+1}
\end{align}
You can simplify the second exponential and proceed in the same way.

**N.B.** The factor $\frac 12$ has been taken out of the square brackets in (1) to get the factor $\frac 1{N\sqrt{2}}$ outside.

**EDIT:** I overlooked the $N$ factor, not really the general case. so I assumed $N = 1$, my bad. But I leave this here anyway.